# Forwarding form to a jsp - showing code after loading page

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have created a form which is forwarded to a jsp. The jsp displays the page but it shows html coding on the page at the top.
Example:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>This page.....</p>
```

It displays this on the jsp aswell as showing the page normal.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Well that doesn't sound right.

Comment: thanks for sorting that out

Comment: What could be the problem?

Comment: No clue. At a minimum we'd need to see more info, e.g., how you're forwarding, from where, what the underlying technology/framework is, etc.

Comment: The jsp runs on tomcat. The page from where I am forwarding from is a simple html page. I'm just forwarding to that jsp. Do I need to put server path or something

Comment: Can you post the result of the page forwarding here so we can see them?